# Smooth Scroll Class doesn't work in Chrome only

Tags: smooth-scrolling

I need some help. I've upload this theme but I notice that the smooth scroll class doesn't work in Chrome. It works in chromium and firefox but in chrome no.
Here is the link:
[website](http://gromu.altervista.org/)

thank you!